# Is this Python unicode escape error?

Tags: python, unicode

I'm learning Python encoding stuffs, I met following situation which is wired for me and I want to know why.

First of all, this is my environment: OSX 10.10.3

Output of the command `echo $LC_CTYPE, $LANG` is:
`en_US.UTF-8, en_US.UTF-8`

Output of `python --version` is `Python 2.7.6`

Then I type `python` to enter python shell:

```
>>> import sys; reload(sys); sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')
<module 'sys' (built-in)>
>>> s16 = u'我'.encode('utf16')
>>> s16
'\xff\xfe\x11b'
>>> for c in s16:
...   ord(c)
... 
255
254
17
98
>>> s16_ = '\xff\xfe\x11\x62'
>>> s16_
'\xff\xfe\x11b'
```

So my question is: For the last line and the 4th line, why Python output `'\xff\xfe\x11b'` instead of `'\xff\xfe\x11\x62'`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When Python prints bytes (`str` in Python 2), it prints the corresponding ASCII character for that byte if it is printable, and hex escapes it otherwise.

`\x62` corresponds to ASCII 'b'. You can see this by just looking at that byte:

```
>>> '\x62'
'b'
```

Comment: Thanks! Is that to say, 'unicode-escape' has done 2 things:
1. For string with any encoding, split it into codes of bytes.
2. For each code which can be printed by the encoding of ascii, print the corresponding character. Otherwise, print the hex format of the code.
That makes it crystal clear. :)

Answer (score 0):

`b` is a printable character, so `repr()` will show the character itself, not the escaped form.

---

Reference: [`str.isprintable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isprintable):

> Note that printable characters in this context are those which should not be escaped when `repr()` is invoked on a string.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation all the same!